# Worker Tiemout Upstream Gunicorn on Docker (Bad Gateway 502)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a platform building on Django, Docker, Nginx and Gunicorn from my Ubuntu server.

Before to ask you, i'm reading about my problem and i did on my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    ...
}
```

Then, on my Gunicorn settings:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-t 90", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

The problem persists and server always returns: 502 Bad Gateway. When i try to access to:

```
http://34.69.240.210:8000/admin/
```

From browser, the server redirect to

```
http://34.69.240.210:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

But show the error:

[image]

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8
  
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-t 90", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.8"
  
services:
  django_app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - static:/code/static
      - .:/code

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static:/code/static
    depends_on:
      - django_app

volumes:
  .:
  static:
```

My **Nginx** file:

```
upstream django_server {
    server django_app:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 34.69.240.210;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Any idea what can i do to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the record.

My problem was the database connection. My Docker container couldn't connect to potsgres local database.

So, i added this line to postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Then, i added this line to pg_hba.conf

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Restart Postgres:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

My host postgres ip:

```
172.17.0.1
```

Test from inside docker:

```
psql -U myuser -d databasename -h 172.17.0.1 -W
```

Done! :)